# Recording audio from RPi3-B1.2, recording video on Windows PC

Tags: audio, video, remote, desktop

I am recording .NET programming videos for YouTube, on Windows 10. 

Because of background noise, I have been trying to record the audio in a different room, while doing the coding remotely from the RPi to the Windows PC. 

I am wondering, how do you get the audio from my mic on the RPi to my Windows PC? An example of what I want to do is here:[image]

Here, I have OBS open on my Windows PC, and the mic is hooked up to it. How would I get the mic audio from the RPi to be used in the Mic/Aux settings? Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly is the question belonging to Raspberry Pi? How to send audio signals through what?

Comment: The local network, to my computer in another room.